# Show that there exists a map which is invertible

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Let $A_1$ and $A_2$ be sets. Let X be any set, given with maps

$p_1:X\rightarrow A_1$ , $p_2:X\rightarrow A_2$

such that for any set T and any maps

$f_1: T \rightarrow A_1$ , $f_2 : T\rightarrow A_2$

there exists a unique map $f : T \rightarrow X$ such that the maps above commutes.

Question : Show that there exists a map $\varphi : X \rightarrow A_1\times A_2$ which is invertible.

My answer : Let $A_1$ and $A_2$ be sets. For any set $X$ and any maps $p_1 : X \rightarrow A_1$ , $p_2 : X \rightarrow A_2$ , there exists a unique map $\varphi : X \rightarrow A_1\times A_2$ such it commutes.

To show that $\varphi : X \rightarrow A_1\times A_2$ is invertible, for any $t \in A_1\times A_2$ , there exists a unique  $a\in A_1$ and there exists a unique $b \in A_2$ such that  $t\in (a , b)$. Thus we have maps $π_{A1} : A_1 \times A_2\rightarrow A_1$ and $π_{A2}:A_1\times A_2\rightarrow A_2$. Therefore, $\varphi:X \rightarrow A_1\times A_2$ is invertible.

Is my solution correct?

**$\pi_{A1}$ and $\pi_{A2}$ , beside the $\pi$ i meant subscript $A_1$ and $A_2$.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Hint* You want to show that $X$ is a product of $A_1,A_2$ in the category of sets. You're basically given that it satisfies the universal property of products, so taking the canonical direct product and using the universal property twice, you should be able to come up with invertible maps from each direction.

To be more detailed. Suppose we have this set $X$. Consider $T=A_1\times A_2$ and the projections $\pi_i:A_1\times A_2\to A_i$. Then the property of the set $X$ gives us a unique map $\varphi:A_1\times A_2\to X$ such that $\varphi p_1=\pi_1$ and $\varphi p_2=\pi_2$. Now consider the maps $p_i:X\to A_i$. We can define a map $\psi: X\to A_1\times A_2$ by $\psi(x,y)=(p_1x,p_2y)$. Note then that $\pi_1\psi=p_1$ and $\pi_2\psi=p_2$, and this is the unique map which such property, that is, this map is determined by the functions in each of its coordinates. Now consider $\psi\varphi$ and $\varphi\psi$. These are maps $A_1\times A_2\to A_1\times A_2$ and $X\to X$ such that $\psi\varphi p_i=p_i$ and $\varphi\psi\pi_i=\pi_i$. But using the property of $X$ with $T=X$, we know there is a unique map $f$ such that $fp_1=p_1$, $fp_2=p_2$; and obviously $f={\rm id}_X$ is such a map. This means that necessarily, by uniqueness, $f=\varphi\psi={\rm id}_X$. The set $A_1\times A_2$ has the same property as $X$ with $\pi_i$ in place of $p_i$ (given maps $f_i:T\to A_i$; it suffices to define $f=(f_1,f_2)$ to get a unique map $f:T\to A_1\times A_2$ for which $\pi_i f=f_i$.) So again, there is a unique map $g$ such that $g\pi_i=\pi_i$, and $g={\rm id}_{A_1\times A_2}$ is such a map. By uniqueness, $\psi\varphi={\rm id}_{A_1\times A_2}$.

Comment: My solution is wrong? :/

Comment: @Joe I don't understand your solution. You must construct $\psi$ such that $\varphi\psi=1$ and $\psi\varphi=1$. You haven't done that.

Comment: can i make a statement "Suppose there exists a map φ : X -> X' and there exists a map ψ : X' -> X such that φoψ= idx' and ψoφ = idx?"